# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-10

I'm getting this error when I try to debug a solution on VS2015 on Amazon Workspace.  I'm using IIS 10.0.19041.1 on Windows 10 and .NET 4.6.2

Under Application Pools in IIS I use the DefaultAppPool
[image]

However, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've noticed that DefaultAppPool stopped implicitly. I start it again but, even though the status is "Started" it's still failing.  I'm not sure that it's running at all which would explain the error.  I've tried other solutions when Windows Fall Center (?) was updated and messed it up.
The suggested fix was to run a script, under admin, on powershell [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1260805/iis-10-cannot-read-empty-configuration-file/1260834)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does Windows event viewer show anything?

Comment: My apologies.  I should have mentioned I'm running this on AWS.  I added that in a recent edit.  As for the event viewer, I see several errors relating to IIS with this text "The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmd5.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

Comment: Check this: https://orcharddojo.net/blog/troubleshooting-iis-apppool-crashes-status-503-after-windows-10-anniversary-update

Comment: I checked and don't have either of those items to repair.  Looking again at the event viewer shows this "The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmd5.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

Comment: I'm missing that dll.  I'm downloading it but shouldn't this be part of Windows 10 install?

Comment: It might not be the exact same DLL as indicated in that link, try doing a repair of your .net installation.

Comment: From registry keys, check if you have ever installed "Digest Authentication", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components

Comment: You can take a look [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2019#server_error), it may help with your issue.